# Oracle column alias in select: is "AS" mandatory?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Does it make any difference omitting the "AS" before defining the name of a column when creating a new view?

```
SELECT
T.STUFF   AS MY_STUFF
```

VS

```
SELECT
T.STUFF      MY_STUFF
```

Comment: Matter of taste. But `T.STUFF      MY_STUFF` makes you wonder whether you forgot a comma.

Comment: Its not specifically in views, also in a simple select it doesn't matter

Comment: Oracle sometimes gives _really_ strange error messages if you omit `AS` and happen to try to use a keyword as an alias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A view is just a [stored query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/schemaob.htm#CNCPT311), so [the `select` syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2126854) applies. As you can see from the syntax diagram for the select list items:

[image]

... the AS keyword in the `expr AS c_alias` section is optional. So no, it makes no difference to the query, database or view. It's for readability and consistency with other database systems. I prefer to use it for anything other than a quick ad hoc query, and you may have coding standards that require it, but Oracle does not care.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't make any difference from the DB's point of view. Personally, I prefer the explicit `AS` and a separate line in my SQL statement per column for a couple of reasons:

- you can easily search for a given column alias (just grep for `AS <alias>`)
- without the `AS`, you might forget a comma - this results in one aliased column instead of two non-aliased ones. If you always use an `AS`, you can spot this kind of error more easily

Answer (score 1):

**NO**, it is just for understandability(readability) purpose.

One would obviously never ever have trouble reading the former with AS. It sounds more logical.

Answer (score 0):

No `AS` is only needed if you plan on using an alias with more than one word separated by spaces or one that requires a certain typecase such as `Employee ID` etc